# Multiple slide outs using the same service

Tags: angular

I have created a data service which is used to toggle my slide out. I want to reuse the service for multiple slide outs but I'm unsure how to do so. Here is what I have so far.

**data-share.service.ts**

```
private slideoutSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true)
slideoutStatus$ = this.slideoutSource.asObservable();

toggleSlideout() {
   const slideoutSource = this.slideoutSource.value;
   this.slideoutSource.next(!slideoutSource)
}
```

**chat.component.ts (contains the trigger for a slide out)**

```
export class ChatsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataShare: DataShareService) { }

  toggleChat() {
    this.dataShare.toggleSlideout();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**chat-window.component.ts (the component that holds the slide out)**

```
export class ChatWindowComponent implements OnInit {
  open: boolean;
  private subscription: Subscription;
  chatTitle = 'Your Conversations';
  
  constructor(private dataShare: DataShareService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.dataShare.slideoutStatus$.subscribe(value => this.open = value);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

So, this seems to work as expected however I want to use the same service to open another unrelated slide out elsewhere in the app. I don't know how to go from what I have at the moment and make it reusable for multiple instances. Can anyone help?

Comment: so basically you want to have many instances of the same Service. So each "feature" aka component have it's own instance, with its own value of the slide-out status?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'chat-window',
  providers: [DataShareService]
})
```

This way the component has his own instance of the service.

Answer (score 0):

I believe better understanding of how the DI in Angular works, will be beneficial. [Here](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) is a complete guide about that, and I will just put a useful summary bellow about your problem:

When you create a service using Angular CLI it by default is provided in root module, and what that means is basically - you will have always a single instance of this class. So no matter how many components will inject that service, they will share the same instance.

In order to provide individual instance for each of the component you have to provide it for the component implicitly.

1. Remove `providedIn: 'root'` in the service file
2. Add service in providers array in each component's meta data:

```js
@Component({
  selector:    'app-chat-window',
  templateUrl: './chat-window.component.html',
  providers:  [ DataShareService ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did try this, however it didn't work for me. I also declared the service as a provider in the module.ts file. The slide out is no longer working. Just to clarify, here are the steps I undertook:

1. Removed the "providedIn: 'root'" from the service file.
2. Listed the service as a provider in the module.ts file.
3. Listed the service as a provider in the component's meta data as you demonstrated above.

Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Looking at the link you provided with more information, it looks like I shouldn't need to register the service in the module.ts file. However, removing it from there has no impact and the slide out still doesn't work.

Comment: it should work, please take a look on this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a99wyt?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

it has Service injected in AppComponent and HelloComponent, both components calls function to increment some count, and you can see in the console, that they both increment independent values.